# Where should I start my LLC?

Tags: taxes, accounting, limited-liability-company, start-up

I want to release an iPhone app to the App Store and want to put my company name as the app's "seller" field.

I was thinking of starting an LLC because I'm working alone and want to hire a developer.

I travel a lot and don't know where I'll end up living. So, where should I start my LLC?

Comment: where do you pay your own taxes? You should probably start there.

Comment: I filed as a Texas resident for 2014, but I'm moving out of my apartment at the end of this month and am not sure where I'll end up next.

Comment: So why not figure that out first?

Comment: Consider these two questions: [When should I start an LLC for my side work?](http://money.stackexchange.com/questions/804/when-should-i-start-an-llc-for-my-side-work?rq=1) and [In what state should I register my web-based LLC?](http://money.stackexchange.com/questions/1145/in-what-state-should-i-register-my-web-based-llc?rq=1)

Answer (score 1):

Individual circumstances may lead you to file almost anywhere, but many firms and individuals file their LLC in Delaware.

Delaware's state government and legal processes have a reputation of being quick, accessible and decisive. Trials are heard by a single judge, not a jury that can deliberate, become hung, and draw out your legal proceedings, costing you time and money.

The LLC entity is designed primarily to afford you legal protection and separate your individual assets from company assets. Delaware ostensibly offers quicker, less painful resolution to any legal disputes that may arise.

Comment: OK. But, if I form my LLC in Delaware, then won't I also have to register a foreign LLC in the state in which I end up living & working? Is it worth the extra effort & fees to file in two states?